# Default Content Access Account

Tags: search

I am setting up search in my environment, so I created a default content access account and it has read permissions on web applications in my environment. But what do I do if I want to search for content in my server itself? How will there be a default access account on local files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For crawling content on file shares, etc, the account must be added on the folders that should be crawled. So it is necessary to set up the NTFS permissions and/or file share permissions with this account.

Then you need to create a new Content Source that will crawl the content from a file share. The documentation for all these above can be found here on this blog:

http://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/10/07/search-content-source-in-sharepoint.aspx

Step-by-step it will handle the important points you need to configure.